# How can i make the buttons on my sideabar switch tabs?

Tags: bunifu

I have a UI with 4 buttons on a sidebar I made and I have no clue how I can set it so when you press it, it shows a different screen.

I do not need it to open a new window just so it can change between 4-5 "modes"

I am using `Bunifu UI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a quick look at the Buniforms reference docs for their WinForms product (I assume you are using their WinForms product) and it look like you want to use the "Transitions" component

https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/bunifu-ui-winforms-docs/#bunifu-transition

"Bunifu Transition is a special component, that allows us to have transitions in our Windows Forms apps. This is an amazing feature of Bunifu Framework, because it makes our User Interfaces more interactive and improves massively the User Experience. Let’s see how!"

"Bunifu Transition allows us to apply transitions to other controls."